# Iframe and App communication inside React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I have built React project **X**(already compiled) and i have other React project **Y**. So i want to use with **Iframe** project X in project Y. I created React component where put `<iframe id="iframe" src="./templates/JobAction/index.html" />` it loads fine but when i want to send data to **Iframe** `iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(dataToSend, '*');` got NOTHING. I had subscribed in project **X**  `window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {console.log(event,888);});` Still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved! Needed just copy Project **X** into output folder with **webpack** `new CopyWebpackPlugin`